# Losing a part of my state in Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I am trying to store the cart state for an ecommerce project. This is my first time using Redux Toolkit. In the first couple of images you can see the setup for the states and what the localstorage looks like when starting.

[Application part of Chrome after clearing cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCvvZ.png)

[cartSlicer for Redux Toolkit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyziX.png)

[store.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJfhP.png)

[storage.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uouXs.png)

Then, after using the application for a bit, I seem to lose the cart_total, cart_quantity and active states, leaving only the "mother" cart state that encapsulates all the states.
[As you can see, I no longer have the objects from the initialState, only "cart"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skcmD.png)

This causes the application to break, since there is no longer a cart.cart level in the localstorage, like in the first image from the dev tools, which causes me to get undefined-errors.

I'm sure this is because I'm probably making a stupid mistake in how I'm setting things up. Any help would be greatly appreciated! If anything was unclear, please let me know!

Best regards, Ragnsan

Comment: Please share code, not screenshots.

Comment: But generally, you have nesting problems here. Please do `reducer: persistedReducer` in your `configureStore` call, or otherwise you end up with `state.cart.cart` without any need.

Comment: @phry Aha! So that's why I was having to do cart.cart! Here is the repo if you have the time to take a look! https://github.com/skaidigitalnorge/okstind/tree/Redux-Toolkit-test

Comment: @phry Just to add some details. I am setting the cart items into the state using a class interface for all the properties of the cart items, which gives me the "A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `register`. Value: [Function: register]"-error. Can this have something to do with it?

Comment: Generally, you should not put classes into Redux state. They cannot be restored by Redux-persist without a lot of extra work and also cause problems with other middleware or the Redux Devtools browser extension.

Comment: @phry That makes sense! I've moved it into an object instead. Though I believe the "register" error is from React Hook Form's ...register, but I guess I can't do anything about that. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Update!

I seem to have solved the issue. I figured out that the state was lost every time I tried to use the removeFromCart dispatcher. I changed it to:

```
removeFromCart(state, action) {
  const index = state.cart_items.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.payload);
  state.cart_items.splice(index, 1);
},
```

Can someone explain why this worked as opposed to:

```
      return state.cart_items.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);
```

Either way, it worked!

Comment: You could have done `state.cart_items = state.cart_items.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload.id);` instead - but if you do `return`, it will replace the full state with what you return.